# viewWillAppear for subviews

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have UIScrollView with multiple UIVIew subviews. I would like to update the data that is displayed by each UIView when they appear in the visible portion of the UIScrollView.

What is the callback that gets triggered? I tried viewWillAppear, but it does not seem to get called.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You have to do the calculation yourself. Implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` in your scroll view delegate and calculate manually which views are visible (e.g. by checking if `CGRectIntersectsRect(scrollView.bounds, subview.frame)` returns true.

Comment: Alright, for some reason I was under the impression that there was a built in callback. Thanks.

Comment: From what I can gather viewWillAppear: and its relatives are only called the first time the view is added to a view hierarchy. Even if the superview's viewWillAppear: gets invoked, those of any subviews already in its hierarchy will not. So for that simple case you need to tell your subviews to refresh from whichever root view gets that message.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, and allowed me to avoid a bunch of manual calculations.

Answer (score 11):

Swift 3 solution

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let viewFrame = greenView.frame

    let container = CGRect(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y, width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)


    // We may have received messages while this tableview is offscreen
    if (viewFrame.intersects(container)) {
        // Do work here
        print("view is visible")
    }
    else{
        print("nope view is not on the screen")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Above answers are correct if your scrollview is not in the zoomed in state. In case if your scrollview can zoom above calculation won't work as you need to consider zoom too

here is the code

```
CGRect visibleRect;
               visibleRect.origin = self.mapScrollView.contentOffset;
                visibleRect.size = self.mapScrollView.bounds.size;

                float theScale = 1.0 / self.mapScrollView.zoomScale;
                visibleRect.origin.x *= theScale;
                visibleRect.origin.y *= theScale;
                visibleRect.size.width *= theScale;
                visibleRect.size.height *= theScale;
                if(CGRectIntersectsRect(visibleRect, btnPin.frame)){
                      ...
                }
```

Comment: This is great! Would not have figured this one out

Answer (score 6):

A slight refinement. I wanted to know the amount of the view that was displayed in the scrollview:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
{
    // Figure out how much of the self.userFeedbackView is displayed.
    CGRect frame = CGRectIntersection(self.scrollView.bounds, self.userFeedbackView.frame);
    CGFloat proportion = (frame.size.height*frame.size.width)/(self.userFeedbackView.frameWidth*self.userFeedbackView.frameHeight);
    NSLog(@"%f; %@", proportion, NSStringFromCGRect(frame));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ole Begemann's answer in swift 5,

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.bounds.intersects(subViewFrame){
            // do something
        }
}
```

Note: Pls make sure that the subViewFrame is calculated with respect to the scrollView's frame.