# How can you check if a view is currently being shown in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiimageview

I've got a scroll view that shows different uiimageviews, and only one is shown at a time (it snaps so there's always only one showing).  How can I check which one is being shown? something like...

```
if(imgView.bounds == self.view.bounds)
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [viewWillAppear for subviews](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950309/viewwillappear-for-subviews/2950979#2950979)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(imgView.frame, scrollView.bounds))
```

(assuming `scrollView` is your UIScrollView)

Comment: if you change "self.view" to "scrollView" i'll give it to you.  thats what ended up working.

Comment: @marty Sorry, thought self.view was your scroll view :)