# Figure out if UIView/Image is currently visible or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

Is there a way to figure out if a View is currently visible/is currently displayed on screen? That'd be really handy for memory handling. Also, is there a way to see if an Image is currently on screen so you don't need to have it in memory all the time, especially if there are a lot of images displayed currently.

Comment: Is this in a `UITableviewCell`? If so, the tableview will manage this for you.

Comment: What do you mean visible? Hidden? Or do you want to check if your View was created yet?

Comment: If the view is currently displayed. If the view has to be drawed or if it is on another viewController, if it is on a level that isn't currently displayed, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to check all of those scenarios. I have never seen a built in property to check for all of those possibilities. Just keep track of where you create, modify and hide the View, and kill it at the appropriate places.

Check if it's hidden:

```
if (view.hidden)
```

or check the hierarchy:

```
if (view.superview == nil)
```

And you can also check the bounds of a view to see if it is on screen.

You can also check alpha:

```
if (view.alpha > 0)
```

That should cover most possibilities, Otherwise, be aware.

Comment: How should I 'check the bounds of a view to see if it is on screen'? That keeps the same even if I change VCs/scroll the ScrollView it's on so that it isn't visible anymore.

Comment: Good point on the scrolling... Didn't think of that. You can use [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2950979/2535467) and calculate to check if the view is still on screen. If you have your view as a subview in a scrollView.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how you're changing Views and imageViews in and out of visibility.  You can check the `hidden` property to see if it's hidden, or check if the the `alpha` property is 0 to see if it's invisible.  When you say "on the screen" it sounds like you might be moving them off the visible edge of the window, in which case you can check `imageView.frame.origin.x` and `y` values to see where it's currently placed.

If you're talking about checking to see if an imageView exists at all, it becomes more complicated.  You could keep an array of them and check to see if it's in there, or several other ways.

Are any of those what you're looking for?  If not, consider editing your question with more details of what you've tried and what you're aiming to do.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a `UITableviewCell`? If so, the tableview will manage this for you.

If it is in a view that you have switched away from via a navigation or tab bar action, see `viewDidDisappear:`

If it is in the current view, but has been moved off the screen, call `convertRect:toView:` on the image view and pass in the main view then check to see if the resulting rect is in the bounds of the main view. Do this after moving the image view.

Comment: Well actually I want to see if the view is on screen at all, there are a lot of things that can happen so that it isn't on screen anymore: it switches to another View controller, it changes its frame, the uiscrollview it is displayed on changes the visible rect,... will I have to check all of them or is there a way to deal with this?

Comment: It's a case-by-case thing. Where does this particular view fit in your view hierarchy? Showing some code and your xib would be helpful here.

Comment: This is about general. All views, all images. I just have a large number of images in my Project on a lot of different ViewControllers and I want to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, assuming `myCustomView` is the view you want to check if it's currently on the screen.

```
// This checks if your custom view's frame is inside self.view.
// You can replace self.view to whichever view that is the current screen of the app

let viewIsVisible = self.view.frame.contains(myCustomView.frame)
```